# Как исправить ошибку, на которую указывает валидатор?

Tags: html, html5, валидация, html-validation

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить ошибку, на которую указывает валидатор? Как только я не пытался исправить эту ошибку, но все мои попытки не дают результата. В чем может быть дело? Благодарю!
В html на странице у меня так:

```
<script src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-tickers.js">
    {
        "symbols": [
            {
                "proName": "INDEX:SPX",
                "title": "Индекс S&P 500"
            },
            {
                "proName": "FX_IDC:EURUSD",
                "title": "EUR/USD"
            },
            {
                "proName": "BITFINEX:BTCUSD",
                "title": "Биткоин/Доллар"
            }
        ],
        "locale": "ru"
    }
</script>
```

Ответ валидатора:

```
The text content of element script was not in the required format: Expected space, tab, newline, or slash but found { instead.
From line 155, column 1; to line 155, column 9
": "ru"↩}↩</script>↩<!--
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. По правилам любое содержимое тега `script` с заданным `src` игнорируется.
   Соответственно, валидатор хочет, чтобы ты удалил содержимое тега.
2. При желании скрипт может читать содержимое тега, хотя браузер его и игнорирует.
   В данном случае в теге находится валидный json.
   Если без этого json'а скрипт ломается, ошибку валидатора следует игнорировать.

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

```html
<script src="data:text/javascript,console.log(JSON.parse(document.currentScript.textContent))">
{
  "symbols": [
    {
      "proName": "INDEX:SPX",
      "title": "Индекс S&P 500"
    },
    {
      "proName": "FX_IDC:EURUSD",
      "title": "EUR/USD"
    },
    {
      "proName": "BITFINEX:BTCUSD",
      "title": "Биткоин/Доллар"
    }
  ],
  "locale": "ru"
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка правильная.Тэг  с атрибутом src может содержать только документацию пробелы и комментарии (/* ... */ or //...).

Comment: @LADYX "скрипт перестает работать".А с чего бы скрипту использовать инкогнито объект?Лично я вижу три ошибки,первая указана выше,вторая уже писал про то что просто фигурные скобки это не объект,во третьих как Вы собрались использовать инкогнито?

Comment: @LADYX Вы предлагаете полностью весь скрипт смотреть?когда не можете исправить ошибку(Тэг с атрибутом src может содержать только документацию пробелы и комментарии (/* ... */ or //...)валидатор все так же выдает на Ваш сайт http://investvesti.ru/ ошибку "The text content of element script was not in the required format: Expected space, tab, newline, or slash but found { instead."

Comment: Вообще, скрипт вполне может читать этот объект...

Comment: @Qwertiy это в данном случае объект?

Comment: В мой ответ загляни.

Comment: Объектом я его назвал потому что он json, содержащий объект.

Comment: @Qwertiy да я понял,начало проскролил не увидел

Answer (score 3):

Содержание тэга `script` с аттрибутом `src` будет игнорироваться, в этом и есть ошибка. Решение - вынести содержание этого скрипта в отдельный скрипт, чтобы получилось следующим образом:

```
<script src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-tickers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mySuperObject = {
        "symbols": [
            {
                "proName": "INDEX:SPX",
                "title": "Индекс S&P 500"
            },
            {
                "proName": "FX_IDC:EURUSD",
                "title": "EUR/USD"
            },
            {
                "proName": "BITFINEX:BTCUSD",
                "title": "Биткоин/Доллар"
            }
        ],
        "locale": "ru"
    }
</script>
```

Если вам нужно передать данные в скрипт выше - рекомендую почитать документацию, скорее всего вам нужно инициализировать этот скрипт(через функцию) и в инициализацию передавать эти данные.

Comment: @LADYX Ошибки в валидаторе нет,единственное будет предупреждение если указать атрибут type

Comment: @LADYX Заверните корневой объект в переменную, сейчас поправлю свой ответ.

Comment: @LADYX Пробуйте так, но советую вам поинтерисоваться, как использовать эти данные, кажется вы делаете что-то не так с этим своим скриптом

Comment: @LADYX Такой вариант не проходит валидацию?

Comment: @LADYX, нет, не может быть, чтобы код из этого ответа не проходил валидацию.

Comment: @LADYX Прямо только что всунул код в валидатор(завернул только в теги `html` и `body`. Валидацию проходит. Ещё раз настоятельно рекомендую прочитать документацию к той библиотеке, которую вы используете. Наверняка там есть раздел инциализации, в котором описано как можно передавать конфигурацию.